# Cakephp - User management System for 2 different users

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. In a project, I have 2 type of users : `Students` and `Admin`. So, I created 2 `Controllers` for 2 type of users, namely, `StudentsController` and `AdminsController`. I have different `Authentication` configuration for these 2 controllers, so I configured `AuthComponent` individually in 2 controllers. And I want a common `login()` function implementation for 2 kind of users, so that I don't have to write same code twice.

Here is my code :

AppController.php :

```
public $components=array('Session','RequestHandler','Acl','Auth'=>array('authorize'=>array('Actions'=>array('actionPath'=>'controllers'))));
```

StudentsController.php :

```
    public function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect=array('controller'=>'students','action'=>'editProfile');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect=array('controller'=>'students','action'=>'index');
        $this->Auth->authenticate=array('Form'=>array('scope'=>array('User.group_id'=>2),'userModel'=>'User','fields'=>array('username'=>'username','password'=>'password')));
        $this->Auth->unauthorizedRedirect=array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login');
        $this->Auth->loginAction=array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login');
        $this->Auth->allow('login','index','createProfile');
        $this->layout='student_layout';
    }
```

AdminsController.php :

```
    public function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect=array('controller'=>'admins','action'=>'myJobs');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect=array('controller'=>'admins','action'=>'index');
        $this->Auth->authenticate=array('Form'=>array('scope'=>array('User.group_id'=>1),'userModel'=>'User','fields'=>array('username'=>'username','password'=>'password')));
        $this->Auth->authError='Did you really think you are allowed to see that ?';
        $this->Auth->unauthorizedRedirect=array('controller'=>'admin','action'=>'index');
        $this->Auth->loginAction=array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login');
        $this->Auth->allow('index');
        $this->layout='admin_layout';
    }
```

UsersController.php :

```
public function login(){
    if($this->request->is('post'))
        if($this->Auth->login()){
            $welcome=($this->Auth->user('group_id')==2)?'Welcome '.$this->Student->field('name',array('Student.id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'))):(($this->Auth->user('group_id')==1)?"<p style='margin-left:20px;color:#366;'><strong>Welcome Admin, You have successfully entered to your Admin Panel!</strong></p>":"");
            $this->Session->setFlash($welcome);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password, please try again');
            $this->set('title_for_layout','Error - Login');
        }
}
```

So, I want that `login` will be handled in `users/login`, for both of users. My code is a little complex, I know. Actually, my `AdminsController`'s `index` page contains the `login form`, which submits to `users/login`.

I mean, `login` logic should be handled in `users/login`, but `login page(login form)` can be different for both of users, only important is that those `forms` should submit to `users/login`.

Now, with these configurations, `Students` cant access `editProfile`, and `Admins` cant access `anything` in the `Admin Panel`.

I think my problem is with `redirecting` after successful login. That's why I used `return` before `$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect())` in the login function.

So, where is the problem ? What should I do ?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Modify this line in core.php :

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin','student'));
```

Add following line in beforeFilter function in app controller :

```
if (isset($this->params['prefix']) && $this->params['prefix'] == 'admin') {
        AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Admin';
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login','admin'=>true);
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'dashboard');
    } else {
        AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Front';
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login',$this->request->prefix=>false);
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard');
    }
```

To get session for admin you use like that

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.Admin');
```

And get front (student)  session as

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.Front');
```

Comment: Looks useful, but unfortunately I still face the problem. Actually, I think my problem is to 'configure' the 'AuthComponent' at the right place. But, still thanks a lot. Do you have any other idea ? @Prakash Saini